# Huge Exp(B) value in categorical binary logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, binary-data

If I run a binary logistic regression with a categorical explanatory variable my results are as below.
When I set the variable to last Variables in the Equation    the values for line I are 
$B= 17.374$, S.E.=1600.042$, Wald= 0.000, \text{d.f}= 1, sig= 0.992, Exp(B)=33831689.7$

All the lines are similar.

If I switch so I am comparing against the first I get this 
$B=-0.365, S.E.=0.338 , Walk= 0.167, \:\text{d.f.}=1, sig=0.280, Exp(B)= 0.694$

Yes I know it is non-significant but all but the last line are significant.

Comment: Please consider what the SE is telling about the estimate.  Could you tell us what "last Variables in the Equation" might mean?

Comment: Did you look at a cross table between your response/dependent/outcome variable and the explanatory variable in question? Also, did you look at the frequency distribution of that explanatory variable? Maybe one of the categories of the explanatory variable is poorly represented in the data (i.e., it appears only a few times)? Or perhaps the explanatory variable has a category for which the response variable has a very small number of (or no) zero/one values? You need to understand your data better so you can diagnose the source of your terrible model fit.

Comment: I think I get it now, the last variable was aged 75+ however there were no responses. Hence a figure of 0 . It is not my data it is secondary analysis of a published dataset.

Comment: If you edit your question to account for your new understanding, it may get further good answers.